# Accept System Alert on iOS real device using Appium

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to automate testing of a mobile application. I am stuck at a point where in the application redirects you to settings and you have to enable "Full Access" for the keyboard. I was able to successfully navigate throughout using "TouchActions" but the issue arose as soon as the system alert pops up. The command simply never stops executing.

I have tried using AutoAcceptAlert, adding a wait for script to wait for the alert to load but it only accepts the app sided alerts and not the system alerts.

The appium inspector is unable to detect the alert and neither am i able to execute the TouchAction using coordinates on the screen. (I know this as the command never stops executing, as seen in debug mode in eclipse).

Command telling us to enable full access gets executed but any "DRIVER" command that follows doesn't stop executing. Soo even if I was using incorrect tap coordinates the command should atleast execute and move over to the next line. 
Example: The command `System.out.println("message")` successfully logs the message to the console but the `driver.tap` command doesn't stop executing.

Is there any way to accept the system alert on a real device?

Is this occurring because changing an App's settings refreshes the application in the background causing the driver to suspend/crash? But shouldn't that happen AFTER accepting the system alert?

Alternatively if there is a way to install messages inside the simulator, that will also provide a workaround for the issue i'm facing.

Here is the appium log for just after

```
action.tap(x, y).perform();
```

Appium-

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"x":192,"y":473}}]}

info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()

info: [debug] [INST] 2016-01-07 03:59:05 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2016-01-07 03:59:05 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2016-01-07 03:59:05 +0000 Debug: Running system command #53: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.795 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.729 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.646 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.636 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.745 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.947 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.632 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.024 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.546 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.075 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.629 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.528 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:29:57 Apps-iPhone Test App[2010] <Warning>: Device is connected to the internet

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:29:58 Apps-iPhone syncdefaultsd[2013] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:29:58 Apps-iPhone syncdefaultsd[2013] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:29:58 Apps-iPhone syncdefaultsd[2013] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:29:59 Apps-iPhone Test App[2010] <Warning>: Success Response: success

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.827 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.627 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.614 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.765 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.859 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.917 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.538 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.545 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.531 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.645 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.745 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.080 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"56d883be-f0b2-4a9a-8818-6744f5d2d199"}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:30:57 Apps-iPhone Test App[2010] <Warning>: Device is connected to the internet

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  7 09:30:58 Apps-iPhone Test App[2010] <Warning>: Success Response: success
```

Comment: as if i  also having same issue http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/how-to-handle-download-dialogs-on-mobile-devices-with-appium